# Segmentation fault occurs because of dirname api for some particular strings (like . and usr)

Tags: c, linux, api, filesystems, dirname

I am seeing the occurrence of Segmentation Fault (segfault) in my program because of an api `dirname` I am using to split a path into directory and file name in my code written in C for Linux.

`dirmane` is used for getting the directory name and `basename` is used to get the file name, according to the instructions [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname).

The barebone code is given below, which compiles and runs fine on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE         
#include <string.h>

void main (void)
{
    char *dirc, *basec, *bname, *dname = NULL;
    char *path = "."; /* I compile this code, for different paths as given below*/

    dirc = strdup(path);
    basec = strdup(path);
    dname = dirname(dirc);
    if (dname == NULL)
    {
        /* precautionary check */
        printf("null pointer\n");
    }
    bname = basename(basec);
    printf("dirname=%s, basename=%s\n", dname, bname);
}
```

I am providing different types of strings in the variable `path` to see how these are split in to 'directory' and 'file name'. I am expecting the end result according to the samples given in above link (pasted below for quick reference).

[image]

When I set path as any of the following samples then I get SegFault because of `dirname` (If I comment it out then I don't get segfault).

```
*path = "."
*path = ".."
*path = "usr"
*path = "usr/"
```

According to the table above, I should not get SegFault but a pointer to '.' string by dirname for such cases. I am not able to get it, as segfault occurs. I added a check for null string as well, as you can see above, to catch any null pointer issue but the program does not reach there as well.

**Let me know if I am missing something or some information is incomplete in this question.**

Comment: Are you getting any warnings during the build process? If so, what are they and why were they not addressed before?

Comment: For this particular program I was getting following warnings:
(1) warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
(2) warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: May this experience teach you *not* to ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: The warning still could not have helped me to get to the fix. I knew there was something wrong but did not exactly know what was the wrong.

Comment: I think it could've, if you had been aware that an undeclared function in `C` is automatically assumed to return an `int`, which in turn should've alerted you to the fact that you were assigning an `int` to a `char *`, which should've caused you to search for the `dirname` function man page (`man 3 dirname`) which listed the `libgen` header you had not yet included, and so on.. In short, *always* try to resolve warnings before anything else :)

Comment: Agreed. Thank you @ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include libgen.h thus dirname is not declared thus it is assumed to return an int thus your program is corrupted and you get a segfault.

Comment: Thanks a lot for it. Including <libgen.h> fixed the issue. Can you describe why was it building (compiling/linking) correctly before but giving segfault for these particular cases?

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood It compiled because why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: I just checked the link I gave in the question, that #include <libgen.h> was given in the synopsis. I did not notice it before. My bad.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood: In general, seg faults are caused by trying to dereference pointers with invalid addresses.

Comment: @immibis I mean if #include <libgen.h> was necessary header for this api then when the header is missing, should not it give error while compiling or linking?

Comment: When a function is not declard, the compiler assumes that it returns an int. If that's not the case, something may go wrong when the function is actually called at run-time, and that's what you got. To avoid such things, use more checks at compilation. For example, if you use gcc, compile with -Wall option.

Comment: @mikedu95 I was not aware of that. The strange world of Linux.

Comment: This is C specification. Nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: On MS Visual Studio, we get compiler error if function declaration is missing.

Comment: Because Visual Studio sets by default warning level to 3 (/W3). The highest level (parano level like -Wall) is level 4.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood  No you don't get a compiler error in that case in Visual Studio either if you compile C code, you do get a warning since warnings are enabled by default. You do however get an error if you use C++ (or compile your C code as C++)